# fadeIn/fadeOut on specified and different button click

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Yesterday I had troubles making something to rise up and down on click of each button.

Thanks to user from stackoverflow "j08691" this problem has been resolved. However, I cannot manage to figureout how do I make content to fadeIn & out depending on each.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H7fPD/4/)

The user that helped me havent seen this one in my question. Perhaps somebody else can help me.

CSS and HTML sample elements has been added in fiddle. I just don't know how to make it work.

For example as in fiddle we have button A, B, C and D.

If "A" is clicked it rises up and `<div id="letterA">Letter A opened-content.</div>` shall appear. If button A is clicked again it should disappear again. (fadeIn & fadeOut).

If Button "A" is active and any other button B, C or D is clicked, again button A will fadeOut the content and other clicked button will appear.

Its really simple to explain, but hard to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KQ3sq/1/

I had to change the markup a bit though. The idea is to link each `li` with its target div. To do that I am using the HTML5 data attributes. You could also consider adding a link with an anchor to the corresponding div (fallback when no JS).

Then the JS doing the magic is:

```
var target = $(this).data('target');    
$("#content").children(target).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
```

Comment: almost there... ^^ Everything works fine until you click same button (example opened A, click on A doesnt close it)

markup changes are fine... :)

Comment: Oh amazing :D guy with tiny JS knowledge will dig into hard stuff and polish :D ! Wish me a luck. Thanks for solution ;)

Comment: Good luck then. Feel free to paste here the fully working updated jsFiddle for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Update @MarvinLabs :D

```
var target = $(this).data('target');    
            $("div#collapseContent").children(target).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
            if($(this).height() != 15 ) $("div#collapseContent").children(target).fadeOut();
```

It work but I am not sure if that is fine or it can be better. So please update your answer or reply here if theres better solution ;)

Cheers and thanks again.